# on click change class

Tags: jquery, onclick, transition, toggleclass

I am testing an animation but I want to know the best way to continually click on a div or input and keep performing the the animation. How do I get the transition to keep repeating every time the image is clicked? 
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #505050;
            }
            .card {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                width: 10%;
                margin-left: 5%;
                margin-right: 5%;
            }
            .spin {
                transform: rotateY(360deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
                -ms-transform: rotateY(360deg);
                -o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
                transition-property: all;
                transition-duration: .5s;
                transition-timing-function: linear;
                -moz-transition-property: all;
                -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
                -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
                -webkit-transition-property: all;
                -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
                -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
                -o-transition-property: all;
                -o-transition-duration: .5s;
                -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
                -ms-transition-property: all;
                -ms-transition-duration: .5s;
                -ms-transition-timing-function: linear;
            }

.rotate {
                    transform: rotateX(360deg);
                    -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotateX(360deg);
                    -o-transform: rotateX(360deg);
                    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
                    transition-property: all;
                    transition-duration: .5s;
                    transition-timing-function: linear;
                    -moz-transition-property: all;
                    -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
                    -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
                    -webkit-transition-property: all;
                     -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
                    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
                    -o-transition-property: all;
                    -o-transition-duration: .5s;
                     -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
                    -ms-transition-property: all;
                    -ms-transition-duration: .5s;
                    -ms-transition-timing-function: linear;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="card">
            <input type="image" id="card" src="images2/Card.jpg" value="1">
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#card").click(function() {
                    $("#card").addClass('spin');
CheckValue($(this).val());
                });
function CheckValue(value)
        {
      selectedImageValue = value;  

 if(selectedImageValue == 1)
                {

$(#card).addClass('rotate');

        }
        }

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can somebody explain the right way to do it. Thanks. I edited my question. I want to add the second class but still have the image animate every time it is clicked. How would I do this please.

OK I made a fiddle example. The problem is you can only flip a card once and I want to be able to flip the card multiple times. I know I am toggeling my class wrong but I don't understand how to reset the class or animation for every click. Can you please fix the code in the else statement to make it animate on each click. Here is the fiddle link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/EJzJA/4/

Comment: make a Fiddle will help us more..

Comment: take a look at http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: hi, I added a fiddle above . If you can still help thanks

Comment: Should I try a css animation instead of transition? Or animate in JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to `add class` on `div` not `input image` Use `.` in place of `#` like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#card").click(function () {
        $(".card").addClass('spin');
     // ---^ use . in place of #
    });
});
```

**[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/vmBSa/1/)**

Above will `animate` only once if you want to `toggle` it many times then you can use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#card").click(function () {
        $(".card").toggleClass('spin');
    });
});
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/vmBSa/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the class after the spin has completed........
Try this piece of code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#card").click(function () {
                $("#card").addClass('spin');
                setTimeout(function () { $('#card').removeClass(); }, 500);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#card").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('spin')){
            $(this).parent().addClass('spin');
            $(this).removeClass('spin');
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().removeClass('spin');
            $(this).addClass('spin');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok. thanks but when i try this every second click makes it spin really big  or differently.. should I make position it  absolute?

Comment: You can position the _parent div_ __absolute__ .

Answer (score 0):

You can toggleClass

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#card").on('click',function() {
                $("#card").toggleClass('spin');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w3cXG/